# SSL is not working in nopcommerce

Tags: ssl-certificate, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.80, nopcommerce-themes, nopcommerce-3.90

I have website `www.perfecthomehealth.com`
on landing page i can see the proper secure (https) but when i move to another page like category or other Product page i am not able to see the secure.

Can you guide me what is the missing and what i need to change in setting?

[image]

Comment: I've seen it, currently your category and product detail pages also with `https`. I think you just need to make `securitysettings.forcesslforallpages` setting true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out the issue actually , My image from Another server so my image url did not have "https" after adding https in image url , Issue has resolved - Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2):

First you need to enable the SSL from Store setting hope you have already did. Then you have to enable "Force SSL for all site pages" from general setting. You must have the SSL certificate at server if not then your cart,checkout, login and admin panel will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have randomly checked category and products pages of the website then they work well. But I have checked the whole website through [this tool](https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/) I found https error 'parts of this page are not secure (such as images)' on some urls. This type of error is called as mixed content (secure and non secure) warning. So with the help of this article based on how to [stop mixed content (secure and non secure) warning](https://www.clickssl.net/blog/how-to-stop-secure-and-nonsecure-items-warning-on-your-site) you can fix your query of non http pages.