# My site has a valid SSL Cert why would my browser say it's not secure?

Tags: ssl

My cert appears to be valid but on the registration page I see an insecure connection warning. Other pages of the site are secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the console in your browser (F12) for warnings. You probably have resources (CSS/ scripts/ images) served over insecure HTTP on that page.

Answer (score 0):

There should be three cases for your query:

1. You are using single domain ssl certificate that secures only one
   domain and your registration page is running on sub domain or other
   domain name.

**Solution:**

If your page is running on other domain name either sub domain or totally different domain name and if requirement to secure only that domain name then take other [single domain SSL certificate](https://www.clickssl.net/cheapest-ssls-for-single-domain-security) to secure only registration page.

2. You have not enabled SSL certificate for registration page.

**Solution:**

Enable SSL certificate for your registration page,if you forgot to include that page. Also use [jitbit ssl tool](https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/) to find that are there other http urls remain on which the same SSL has not enabled. If found any then enable SSL on them too to avoid mixed content warning.

3. Some Content (like images, url etc.) of registration page is on http
   page.

**Solution:**

Checkout reference link how to deal with [secure and non secure content warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106928/ssl-is-not-working-in-nopcommerce/45140345#45140345).